# Fill different columns based on other columns (first one with column header, second one with the value to obtain)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with Python 3.6.9.

I'm stuck on a dataframe like that :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_ = {'col1': [3.14, 28, -0.618, 1.159], 'col2': ['a_002_u', 'a_003_u', 'a_001_u', 'a_003_u'], 'a_001_u': [np.nan] * 4, 'a_002_u': [np.nan] * 4, 'a_003_u': [np.nan] * 4}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)

     col1     col2  a_001_u  a_002_u  a_003_u
0   3.140  a_002_u      NaN      NaN      NaN
1  28.000  a_003_u      NaN      NaN      NaN
2  -0.618  a_001_u      NaN      NaN      NaN
3   1.159  a_003_u      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

And I would like to get this result :

```
     col1     col2  a_001_u  a_002_u  a_003_u
0   3.140  a_002_u      NaN     3.14      NaN
1  28.000  a_003_u      NaN      NaN   28.000
2  -0.618  a_001_u   -0.618      NaN      NaN
3   1.159  a_003_u      NaN      NaN    1.159
```

In other words, I would like to fill columns 'a_001_u',  'a_002_u',  and 'a_003_u' with 'col1' values based on column header in 'col2'.

It is quite easy to explain, but I have the impression that it is less obvious to set up.
Does anyone have an idea to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html?highlight=fillna#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) after change the shape of the first 2 column with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) like:

```
df = df.fillna(df.set_index('col2', append=True)['col1'].unstack())
print (df)
     col1     col2  a_001_u  a_002_u  a_003_u
0   3.140  a_002_u      NaN     3.14      NaN
1  28.000  a_003_u      NaN      NaN   28.000
2  -0.618  a_001_u   -0.618      NaN      NaN
3   1.159  a_003_u      NaN      NaN    1.159
```

because actually doing the `set_index` and `unstack` does create the other columns you want, and the `fillna` will do a (row,column) filling of missing value

```
print(df.set_index('col2', append=True)['col1'].unstack())
col2  a_001_u  a_002_u  a_003_u
0         NaN     3.14      NaN
1         NaN      NaN   28.000
2      -0.618      NaN      NaN
3         NaN      NaN    1.159
```

NB: Same result could be obtain with pivot like `df.pivot(columns='col2', values='col1')`

Comment: This solution works perfectly. And that's exactly what I was looking for. I did not know the association "set_index" and "unstack". Thanks a lot ! @Ben.T

Comment: @David it is equivalent to a pivot, you could get the same result with `df.pivot(columns='col2', values='col1')`, which could be faster actually ;)

Comment: Totally agree with @Ben.T , pivot is a good tool to use in this case given you have a a large number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it by iterating through the rows.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row[row['col2']]=row['col1']
```

Comment: I have tens of thousands of data frames, and each one contains several thousand rows. So I'm looking for (if possible) a solution by vector calculation to be as fast as possible. I'm afraid that with a loop for it would take too long... Thanks for your help @overflow95

Comment: I get an error 'TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [3.14] of <class 'float'>'

Comment: Hi @Sowmya, thanks for noticing. It should be `row['col1']` instead of `row[row['col1']]`

Comment: @overflow95 You are welcome. I was wondering why the loop should take long?

Comment: @Sowmya for more information about `iterrows` vs `vectorization`, read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9274732), it is really good :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dict_ = {'col1': [3.14, 28, -0.618, 1.159], 'col2': ['a_002_u', 'a_003_u', 'a_001_u', 'a_003_u'], 'a_001_u': [np.nan] * 4, 'a_002_u': [np.nan] * 4, 'a_003_u': [np.nan] * 4}

df = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
count = 0
for key in df['col2']:
    df[key][count] = df['col1'][count]
    count += 1

df
```